# Docker compose MySQL-volumes invalid invalid specification

Tags: docker-compose, volumes

I am using service 3 and below is mycode,

I tried to add the var- COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS: 1 in environment

it still get the error:

ERROR: for db-on-docker-ms_mysql-dev_1  Cannot create container for service mysql-dev: invalid volume specification: '/c/Dockerfile/db-on-docker-ms:/var/lib/mysql under volumes:rw'

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blogapp
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
  volumes:
    - /c/Dockerfile/db-on-docker-ms:/var/lib/mysql
```

My Docker Version: 18.09.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Misantorp's ans first!

I finally figure out how to do it in windows container

the volumes path should be:

```
volumes:
  - C:\Dockerfile\db-on-docker-ms:/var/lib/mysql
```

run the command in powershell:

COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=0

then run:

docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

I think you either need set `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` environment variable from your command line

```
$ export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

Then change the `volumes` configuration

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blogapp
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
  volumes:
    - c:\Dockerfile\db-on-docker-ms:/var/lib/mysql
```

Run docker compose

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Or you can attempt to set the `volumes` like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-dev:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blogapp
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
  volumes:
    - //c/Dockerfile/db-on-docker-ms:/var/lib/mysql
```

And run docker compose

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
But neither does it work :'(